# Why am I getting this error in Cappuccino: "missing ; before statement : if(_2f5===_2e4){"

Tags: cappuccino

I have been developing with cappuccino for a while now and all of a sudden I am getting a weird error with "Objective-J.js".

The error message is:  "missing ; before statement : if(_2f5===_2e4){"

I am having a really hard time figuring out what is causing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using index-debug.html

It's probably advisable to also run your code through a lint application. You can find links to some if you search the mailing list.

Comment: I have also tested with index-debug.html and am getting the same errors. Do you know of an Objective-J linter?